# How right arrange the items in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-phone

```
<Button x:Name="TestButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,0,0,0" FontSize="19" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" Visibility="{Binding IsTaskRun,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

In what order must be placed so that its properties it was right?

Comment: The order of the properties doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 for Clemens' comment. You would however not need to set all layout properties for each and every concrete UI element all over the place if you'd use (more or less) "global" `Style`s in a WPF `ResourceDictionary`(s)

Comment: I understand that,but easier to read when they are ordered as either

Comment: Order is not a matter. But if you want to be clean, use in all your xaml code same order. Eg: if you provide first the name, then HorizontalAlignment... do the same in the following xaml object if they contain the same properties. If not, try to keep the same order. It's not mandatory, only an advice. But I use to start with `name`, then `positioning` and `style`, then `commands` and `bindings`.

Answer (score 0):

To align content of the button to the right use this:

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
```

**EDIT:**

As the comments above indicate it doesn't really matter which order you place them in. There is no rule for that. You have to find your own way/style of doing it, so it is easier for you to read. 
In case you are programming in a group then you should find a way/style that suits the group.
Personally I would like to write all properties in one line, doesn't really matter how big the line become. But if you look at MSDN templates, then they like to have each property in one line:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I want in what order must be placed this properties for Good Code Style

Comment: Do you mean how to order the properties of the button ? Like which comes first, HorizontalAlignment or VerticalAlignment ?

Answer (score 0):

The order of attributes is invalid. There is no particular order. With that said, I hate that VS forces all attributes all on one line, so I just put them all on their own line.

Like:

```
<Button
    x:Name="TestButton"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Margin="12,0,0,0"
    FontSize="19"
    IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"
    IsRightTapEnabled="False"
    Visibility="{Binding IsTaskRun,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Now, it's all just personal preference really. I find this more readable, and someone might disagree. Unless you have a boss dude telling you to format code in a certain way, choose a format that suits you.